# it’s possible that swap transaction get executed some blocks later

Tags: evm, pending-transactions, decentralized-exchange, txpool, uniswapv3

i want call X function, there are multiples external calls in this function.one of this external calls is a DEX trade. it’s possible this DEX trade transaction get executed in the some blocks later or X function and all external calls with it will get executed in one block ?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely no it shouldn't be able execute the swap later. Though to be certain we would need the specific implementations.

In general, X function and all its external calls should execute within the one transaction or the entire "atomic operation" should be rolled back. Nothing is left in memory and no states are changed unless the transaction lands on chain.

If you are sending bundles and it is one of multiple transactions in a block that need to execute in order (as with a sandwich attack), and/or you are using "permits" to allow tokens to be taken from you at some later point (as with a limit order protocol), there could be some cases where that was exploited.
For example if the block is "uncled", then just your permitting/order placing transaction could land on chain.

If it is a Uni v2 style swap, you should be able to look at how the "deadline" field is set from the calling contract in its call to the router, and it may well be for the current block only.
If you are writing the calling contract you can use such a safe guard.

There are some uncommon try-except implementations, and ways to use a raw call to recover from a reversion, but if calling a well known dex from a contract not designed specifically to trick you into signing a permit, that shouldn't be a threat in terms of delayed execution.

As a rule don't deploy and send funds to any contract you don't understand. Be especially careful of the copy and paste MEV bots from youtube and similar.